# RecyclerView items shown horizontaly with blocking on Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

i have a `RecyclerView` which single item is `CardView` type. I want to display that `Cardviewes` with `match_parent` width, and go next by finger swipe. I set an horizontal orientation in LinearLayout and everything is OK, but i can scroll it like a regular List but i want to make that finger swipe is scrolling that items and block on next one without scrolling through whole list. Is this possible in some way ?

Comment: Use [View Pager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide)

Comment: Can i connect it with Recyclerview ?

Comment: Use them instead RecyclerView